# PHP form with image upload

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple contact form page with a combination of HTML and PHP with an upload image file section to it. I am 99% sure I got the HTML part correct but I am just lost with the PHP part.

So here is my HTML

```
<form class="" action="contactform.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
  <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your e-mail" required>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
   <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And here is my PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  
  $mailTo = "email@email.com";
  $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
   $subject = "You have received an e-mail from your web site";
  
  $message = "First Name: " . $firstname . " Last Name: " . $lastname . "\r\nPhone: " . $phone . "\r\nemail: " . $mailFrom . "\r\nMessage: " . $message;

$retval = mail( $mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers );
      
      if ( $retval == true ){
        echo "<h1>Message Sent</h1>
        <p>Thank you for contacting us your message has been sent successfully and we will get back to you a soon as possible.</p>";
      }
      else {
        echo "<h1>Message Sent</h1><p>Message could not be sent Mail server did not accept mail.</p>";
      }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can make the upload file part work?

Comment: I suggest reading the PHP documentation regarding file uploads: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0):

try changing `if($retval==true)` to `if($retval!=false)` because I believe it only returns false if it fails and if it is successful it will return a hash value, so I believe making sure it's not true will work.

Also just you might want to take `mail( $mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers );` and copy it into its own function, but I'm not sure. Kinda like this:

```
$retval = mail( $mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers );
mail( $mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

I'm not sure though, I hope this works, sorry if it doesn't!

Comment: oof you changed your question, I'll see if I can make a new answer!